# Multiple calls to scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) in quick succession causes scrolling glitch in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

In my setup I have a horizontal collection view with chip style, on initial load the first chip is selected by default and corresponding to the chip an API call is made and it's data is loaded into a vertical UICollectionView right below.

On tapping any of the chips in the UICollectionView an API call is initiated and the selected cell is scrolled into the centre of collectionview using `scrollToItem(at: selectedChipIndexPath, at: .centerHorizontally , animated: true)`. Plus I have to reload the the last selected & current selected indexPath to indicate that new cell is selected.

Everything works fine if user taps on the chips, looks at the below loaded data and then taps on the next chip.

But if the user taps on consecutive chips quickly then `scrollToItem(at: selectedChipIndexPath, at: .centerHorizontally , animated: true)` glitches the scroll animation some times causing an unpleasant UX experience.

Here is my code:

```
horizontalCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [lastSelectedIndexPath, selectedChipIndexPath])

// API Call
/*
   This is an async call, which ones finishes informs the ViewController to the update it's vertical collection view with new data
*/
viewModel.fetchProductData(forPositon: selectedChipIndexPath)

DispatchQueue.main. asyncAfter ( .now() + .seconds(0.4)) {
   horizontalCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: selectedChipIndexPath, at: .centerHorizontally , animated: true)
}
```

If I don't delay the scrolling by few milliseconds then scroll animation of collection view starts to glitch very badly.

So can anyone point me in the right direction on how can I handle or queue up multiple `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` calls so that my collectionView scroll animation doesn't glitch.

I did try to wrap `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` in batch updates but it didn't work.

**Update 1:**

Here's how my UI looks mostly

Horizontal Collection View : For Product Categories

Vertical Collection View : For Products themselves

[image: Visual Representation on how my UI looks]

**Update 2:**

The solution provided by **DonMag** works but it introduces another problem, according to my designs I have to change the font type from regular to bold for the UILabel inside the chips when selected, doing this causes the label frame size to increase and for most text the label gets clipped since I am just manipulating the views instead of reloading the cells themselves.

I tried to invalidate the CollectionView Flow Layout. But it again brought me to the same problem of the scrolling glitch.

Comment: What is *"chip style"*? Why are you reloading *the last selected & current selected indexPath*? It's not clear what you're doing with your "API call" -- in `didSelectItemAt`, are you making an "API call" ... waiting for it to finish ... and then reloading your cells and calling `scrollToItem`? If so, is the problem that the user selects a different item during that process?

Comment: @DonMag Have updated my question with an example UI. I am updating the last & current selected IndexPath for selection (passing a bool to indicate the selected & un selected stated). The API call is async, once it fetches data, the viewModel informs the VC using 2 way binding to update it's UI. Once any chip is selected I am scrolling it to the centre and tapping on consecutive chips in quick succession is causing the scrolling animation to glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code, the issue is likely being caused by your repeated calls to `.reloadItems(...)`

If you are doing that only to change the **appearance** of the selected cell, it is unnecessary.

Instead, let the collection view track the selected cell (as it does by default), and have your cell modify its own appearance based on its selected state.

For example - if we create a cell with a single label in a typical manner like this:

```
class SomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "SomeCell"
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])


        // default "un-selected" appearance
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentView.bounds.height * 0.5
    }

    // the collection view will tell us whether the cell is selected or not
    //  so update the cell appearance here
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0) : .systemBackground
            contentView.layer.borderWidth = isSelected ? 0.0 : 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

We've overridden `var isSelected: Bool` ... the collection view will set that property when needed, and now our cell updates its "selected / un-selected" appearance automatically.

No need to call `.reloadItems`

Example view controller with horizontal collection view using the above cell - note that I'm creating 4 "repeating sets" of the sample tags (prefixed by 1-4), so we have plenty of cells to scroll:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var sampleTags: [String] = [
        "Pomogranate",
        "Banana, Guava, Sapota",
        "Oranges, Mosambi",
        "Apple",
        "Blueberry",
        "Pineapple",
        "Strawberry",
    ]
    var tagsData: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // let's create several sets of the sample tags
        //  so we have plenty of cells to scroll
        for i in 1...4 {
            sampleTags.forEach { s in
                tagsData.append("\(i): \(s)")
            }
        }
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.estimatedItemSize = .init(width: 80.0, height: 40.0)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SomeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SomeCell.identifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tagsData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SomeCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SomeCell
        c.theLabel.text = tagsData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // scroll the selected cell to the center
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.viewModel.fetchProductData(forPositon: indexPath)
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - *additional requirement: cell font change to bold when selected, without causing cell size change...*

The easiest way to do that is to add **two** labels to the cell - one with Bold font, the other with Regular font.

Setup the constraints so the Bold label will control the width and the Regular label will be slightly wider than necessary.

Show the Bold label when selected, show the Regular when not.

So, slightly modified cell class from above:

```
class SomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "SomeCell"
    
    public var title: String = "" {
        didSet {
            theLabel.text = title
            theBoldLabel.text = title
        }
    }
    
    private let theLabel = UILabel()
    private let theBoldLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        [theLabel, theBoldLabel].forEach { v in
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theBoldLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            theBoldLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theBoldLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theBoldLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),

            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theBoldLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theBoldLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theBoldLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theBoldLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        theLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .regular)
        theBoldLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .bold)

        // not strictly necessary, but the bold label controls the sizing
        // so let's make sure it sizes correctly
        theBoldLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        theBoldLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
        // default "un-selected" appearance
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        theBoldLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    
    // the collection view will tell us whether the cell is selected or not
    //  so update the cell appearance here
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0) : .systemBackground
            contentView.layer.borderWidth = isSelected ? 0.0 : 1.0
            theLabel.isHidden = isSelected
            theBoldLabel.isHidden = !isSelected
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentView.bounds.height * 0.5
    }
}
```

Then in the controller's `cellForItemAt`, instead of setting the text of the "single" label, we'll set the cell's `title` property, which will set the same text in both labels:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SomeCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SomeCell
    //c.theLabel.text = tagsData[indexPath.item]
    c.title = tagsData[indexPath.item]
    return c
}
```

---

**Edit 2** - *responding to comment about selecting programmatically...*

First, do **NOT** call:

```
cell.isSelected = true
```

That does not tell the collection view that the cell has been selected.

This is the proper way to programmatically select a cell (in this case, we want to select cell/item `5` and have it scroll to the center):

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
```

Note that *programmatically* selecting the cell will ***NOT*** call the `didSelectItemAt` delegate func. That is called to let you know that the *user* selected a cell.

So, if you want to programmatically select a cell, **and** you want something to happen, follow it up with that "do something" code.

For example:

```
let idxPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0)
collectionView.selectItem(at: idxPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.viewModel.fetchProductData(forPositon: idxPath)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DonMag for the guidance, I'll try to implement this and report back asap.

Comment: The above answer fixes my problem, but it introduces another problem. The UILabel inside chips when selected change from Regular to Bold Font Type which increases their size causing the text to clip. To resolve this issue I tried to invalidate the flow layout, but it again brought me to the same problem of scrolling glitch. Earlier since I was reloading the cells, this problem didn't occur but now since there is no reloading this problem arose.

Comment: @NikhilMuskur - it helps to provide complete information when posting a question. Do you ***want*** the "chip" width to change when the font is bolded? Or, do you want a consistent width, and just have the font change?

Comment: @NikhilMuskur - I added an **Edit** to my answer... see if that is what you needed.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, this resolves my query and issue. Any hints on how can I select the cell using the above technique, programmatically. I tried ```cell.isSelected = true; collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath)``` but this didn't work

Comment: @NikhilMuskur - see the **Edit 2** to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit, this resolves all my issues and my feature is implemented. Finally I can stop managing UICollectionView & UITableView selection manually